# Cannot convert @drawable/ into a drawable

Tags: android, drawable, imagebutton

I have been getting some weird error when trying to add a default drawable to my app. 
"Failed to convert @+drawable/ic_delete into a drawable"

in my xml i wrote the following

```
  <ImageButton 
      android:id="@+id/cancel1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Till1"
      android:src="@+drawable/ic_delete"/>
```

I have read somewhere that restarting eclipse solves the problem... but it didnt solve mine 
please help and TIA

Comment: Have you tried just `@drawable` not `@+drawable`?

Comment: Well I have tried that ... it didnt work
It just said"error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_delete')."

.. any more suggestions?

Comment: I hope the image format is .png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "+" comes only when you add a new id to a view. Here in your case you are not adding a id but just assigning a src for the imagebutton. Therefore, you need not have + sign there.
try android:src=@drawable/ic_delete.

Comment: Well I have tried that ... it didnt work It just said"error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/ic_delete')." .. any more suggestions?

Comment: Can you check whether you have the image file named ic_delete? Do a clean first and then build it. Check the r.java file inside the gen folder for this image name.

Comment: "do a clean"? may please explain ?

Comment: If you are using eclipse do, project->clean. this will delete the files under gen folder.  Not sure what is the equivalent for android studio.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
android:src="@+drawable/ic_delete"
```

with

```
android:background="@drawable/ic_delete"
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your R file in gen folder.

It contains drawable field like this

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
    }
```

check your image name in this.

If it is not containing then please check your All layout(xml) files. whether is it ok or not. sometimes incorrect xml file will occure errors in R.java file .

If all layouts are ok then check your image name. uppercase is not allowed for resource names.. only lowercase(a-z), 0-9, .(dot) and _ are valid.

Then `Clean` (select your current project -> click on `Project` from tab bar -> select Clean) your project.

If all thing is perfect then Restart your eclipse then clean & build your project.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this

`android:src="@+drawable/ic_delete"`

to

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use `+` when you create new id not when you use it 
and for the error try to close Eclipse or Android Studio and reopen.
If thats doesn't solve it, you must check your image size and image extension